# asciidoc: custom list symbols

Tags: custom-lists, asciidoc

Is it possible in asciidoc to choose your own list symbols. In my case I would like to use check marks, but question applies to any symbol in general.

For example, I would like the output to look like:

```
✓ Apples
✓ Bananas
✓ Cherries
```

etc

Answer (score 0):

The [asciidoctor User Manual](http://asciidoctor.org/docs/user-manual/#custom-markers) mentions custom markers as a feature (squares, circles and discs seems to be the only possibilities).

```
[square]
* one
* two
* three
```

In your case you can maybe use [the checklist](http://asciidoctor.org/docs/user-manual/#checklist) as a replacement.

```
- [ ] not checked
- [X] checked
```

Comment: The asciidoc manual calls it 'custom marker', but in fact, these are predefined markers. It's sad that asciidoc does not support custom defined markers.